# Самые известные методы сортировки

Tags: сортировка, c++

Прошу привести самые известные методы сортировок, исключая метод пузырька,
и привести реализации их алгоритмов на языке C++.

Также прошу отметить, какой из них самый оптимальный (имеется в виду скорость работы программы).

Comment: Гугль в помощь. В Википедии все это имеется. А самой быстрой считается считается сортировка Хоара, она же quick sort.

Comment: Шилдт. Справочник С,С++ там очень-очень хорошо и подробно расписано.

Comment: Я начал играться с сортировкой слиянием. Вообще-то цель сделать ее с минимальной дополнительной памятью, но за время лучше n (log n)^2

Достаточно тривиальный вариант (дополнительная память n/2+1) оказался (gcc -O3) быстрее qsort. Для 10000000 int qsort = 2945 msec, а  msort = 1465 msec. на DualCore 2.7 GHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разберись с функцией qsort. Погугли  про нее сам.

Comment: Кстати, сравнивал производительность qsort и std::sort в Visual Studio. Второй оказался быстрее примерно на 15%.

Comment: Я думаю, тут еще рано о шаблонах говорить. А за информацию спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Одним из самых быстрых считается метод [быстрой сортировки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), [метод Шелла](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0) тоже довольно неплох.

[Метод вставок](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) для массивов работает относительно медленно, но если его использовать для сортировки списков, может дать неплохой результат.

[Метод слияния](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC) тоже обычно используют для списков.

[Метод выбора](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) используют тогда, когда требуется использовать как можно меньше операций перезаписи (например при внешней сортировке на флеш-носителе), но он относительно медленный.

[Сортировку по дереву](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0) обычно используется когда в результате нужно получить двоичное дерево для поиска.

Обзор методов и их классификация есть здесь: [Алгоритмы сортировки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Алгоритмы описаны в соответствующих статьях Википедии.

Answer (score 1):

Функция [sort](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/). На [русском](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/ru/algorithm/sort).

Comment: К какой библиотеке она принадлежит?

Comment: > К какой библиотеке она принадлежит?

На обоих страницах есть примеры, из которых ясно к какой библиотеке она принадлежит. На cplusplus.com сверху в правом углу также указано название библиотеки. Читайте внимательнее.

Answer (score 1):

"Так же прошу отметить какой из них самый оптимальный(имеется в виду скорость работы программы)"

Самого оптимального алгоритма нет, просто одни более стабильны, другие лучше работают при сортировке больших объемов элементов, другие эффективней при сортировке нескольких элементов, короче, для каждого алгоритма есть свой случай сортировки, в котором он наиболее эффективен.

[Wiki: Алгоритм сортировки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Здесь ссылки на большинство методов сортировки, и практически к каждому есть пример на разных языках.

P.S.
Google + Wikipedia делают чудеса

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что никто не упомянул [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). Это достаточно новый алгоритм (2002 г.), который на реальных данных часто показывает лучшие результаты, по сравнению с другими известными алгоритмами. На данный момент он является основным методом сортировки в Python и Java.
Реализация на C++ есть например по ссылке https://github.com/swenson/sort.

Comment: Алгоритм очень интересный. Но у него расход дополнительной памяти O(n). 

Интересно, никто не пытался модифицировать сортировку слиянием с использованием только небольшого дополнительного буфера, а в основном "на месте" - для откладываемых элементов использовать освобождающуюся память в одном из сливаемых подмассивов ?